# Use of case without switch, please explain the output of this code

Tags: c++, switch-statement

We use cases with switch. But here the cases are inside the default case, so it should require one more switch. But the code doesn't give any compile time errors.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int num=4;
    while (num)
    {
        switch(num)
        {

            default:
                case 1:
                    std::cout<<"Executing "<<num<<"\n";
                
                case 2:
                
                case 3:
    
                break;
        }
        num--;          
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover the output is Executing 4 and then Executing 1. According to me the output should be Executing 1 because each time default is being entered. It will enter case 1 when value is 1. But first please explain how this is compiling, because according to me there should be a nested switch.

Comment: "_inside_"?  No, they are all on the same lavel. C++ does not care about your indenting (unlike `python`). Add `std::cout << num << '\n';` above the `switch` and it'll become clear what happes.

Comment: Misleading indent. default and case 1 are on the same level. And if you do not put a break between cases they fall through. So 1 or default=anything that's not a 2 or 3 will print.

Comment: That's just wrong indentation. The `case`s come from the `switch`, they are on the same level as the `default`.

Comment: I was stuck at this for some time now. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2):

In a `switch`, all `case` and `default` are at the same level, you were just caught by the (stupid?) indentation, and a rather inconsistent use of default. In fact it should read:

```
    switch(num)
    {
            default:
            case 1:
                std::cout<<"Executing "<<num<<"\n";
            
            case 2:
            case 3:
                break;
    }
```

Meaning: do nothing (break) if 2 or 3, and display `Executing ...` for 1 or any other value.

This would do the same and would be IMHO more readable:

```
    switch(num)
    {
        case 2:
        case 3:
            break;

        default:
            std::cout<<"Executing "<<num<<"\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`case` 1 to 3 are indented wrongly.

It's a so-called "fallthrough".
If the switch hits the `default` case, it will fall through until it reaches a break meaning it will execute other cases on the way.
In your case, if it hits the `default` case, it will execute `case 1`, `case 2` and `case 3`

Edit: I recommend ending each case with a `break` and putting `default` as the last case.
Only if you really want to fallthrough and know what you do you could omit the `break`.